# How to create confirmation page for external links

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

Some of the download links of my blog are from some external sites. I want to put a confirmation page like this one https://codyhouse.co/demo/simple-confirmation-popup/index.html
for those links saying some disclaimer for using the contents of the external sites. Visitor can either agree to continue or disagree to return to my page.

Like something below:

1. (www.example1.com) Click here to download (www.example2.com/download.zip)
2. Goes to (www.example1.com/disclaimer.html) disclaimer page.
3. Agree (goes to www.example2.com/download.zip)
   or, disagree (goes to www.example1.com)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you'd need to select all these links, something like;

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('a[target]');
```

This will give you an array of all external links (in this case I've defined them as any anchor links with a target attribute, but you can use whatever)

The you'll need to prevent the default behavior on each of them (so that they don't go anywhere before you've shown your disclaimer), something like;

```
for(var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
    ele[i].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
};
```

Lastly after the preventDefault, you'll need to show your popup and then send the user there if they are ok, and do nothing (close the popup) if they aren't ok. In this case I'm just using a confirm popup, but you can add this into any dom popup should you wish:

```
if(confirm('really go to this link?')) {
    window.location = this.href;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the same with simple javascript confirm box it can be done by the below block of code.

```
function onClickEvent(){
   if(confirm("Your Disclaimer !!!")){
      //redirect to the url
      location.href = "http://www.example2.com/download.zip";
     }
   return;
}
```